# Tweaking md5 hash string of a file on the HTTP Header Request - MegaUpload

Tags: php, apache, curl, upload

MegaUpload.com's upload process **would NOT really upload your file IF it saw that the file you are going to upload is already on their server**, instead it will just copy it (probably symlink only) to the uploader's account.

I would like to write a script that would read the File's **Size and md5 hash string** via HTTP Header's Response, and I would just generate a dummy file (fake file) with the same size and force that file to have the same md5 hash string on the HTTP Request.

Is it possible? please show me how to do it? has anyone done a cURL script like this?

thanks

Comment: This question makes little sense as it stands. Are you trying to replicate MegaUpload's functionality? What do you mean by "generate a  dummy file"?

Comment: Also note that the MD5 of a file is *not* sent as a header by any web browser I know.

Comment: Read up on how to generate MD5 collisions. Explaining it to you is *way* outside the scope of this site, doubly so if you need to match both the MD5 *and* size of the input.

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ: I would create a file locally with the same size but randomly generated content, below is a snippet

`$handle = fopen($filename, "a+");`
`# build the fake file`
`for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++){`
`   $content .= chr(mt_rand(0,255));`
`}`

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: in order NOT to download the desired file (especially if its a large file) on the firsthand, and then eventually upload the generated file to megaupload

Comment: @macki Then you would be uploading a dummy file instead of the real one to MU. What's the point of this?

Comment: I was wondering if I'll be uploading a dummy file with a copied md5 hash string, MU would recognize that it already exist in their server, and it would just copy the existing file to the uploader's account.
is it possible?

Comment: @macki It certainly is *possible* but there are two problems with that: 1) If the file *doesn't* exist on MU, they'll use your dummy file. Now the original file can no longer be uploaded. 2) No browser I know sends the MD5 of a file as a header, so you'll have to get the file from the user. In that case, why not just upload the real thing to MU?

Comment: thanks for the effort, I realized I'm doing a wrong algorithm